# switchMap with empty return not working - error "Cannot read property 'uid' of null"

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm afraid I'm not getting anywhere. I had bought a tutorial, but angular is there version 4. I now have the 12.
Much I could understand about googel then yet, but now I get no further even with Google.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { map, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { EMPTY } from "rxjs";


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  user1: Observable<any>;

  constructor(
    private userService: UserService,
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, 
    private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.user1 = afAuth.authState;  
  }

  login(){
    let returnUrl: any = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('returnUrl' || '/');
    localStorage.setItem('returnUrl', returnUrl);

    this.afAuth.signInWithRedirect(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()); 
  }

  logout(){
    this.afAuth.signOut();
  }


get appUser1(): Observable<any>{
    return this.user1    
      .pipe(switchMap(user => this.userService.get(user.uid).valueChanges()))  
  }
}
```

Login works but Logout not. If i press the logout-Button (in the Browser) it shows error:
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of null

In the Tutorial he says. i Need to change the ".pipe" for fix this bug, to:

```
.pipe(switchMap(user => {
  if (user) return this.userService.get(user.uid);

  return EMPTY;
}));
```

("EMPTY" was in tutorial "Observable.of(null)", but i found out its not actual anymore)
than i have a compilition error at "user =>" before some hours i fixed it, but i can not remember how. But anyways. Logout was also not working this way.

At Google i found a lot about this topic, but i did not understand/it is not working for me. Why i can not return this empty at the else-case?

Comment: There seem to be a lot of logic related (obviously not listed) by looking at the snippet, try adding filter(user=> !!user && !!user.uid) before switchMap pipe.. Basically, the error says user is null so you need to make sure user has a value once switchMap executes

Comment: Also, change the type of `user1` to whatever type is assigned to `afAuth.authState`.

Comment: "*Logout was also not working this way*" - What do you mean "not working"? It seems like your fix with returning EMPTY should solve the "cannot access uid of null" problem.  What is the issue with the logout behavior?

Comment: @KQI this does not work.
after adding "filter" it shows compelition error "Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Observable<User | null>'."

Comment: Filter is another rxjs operator, make sure it is included in your component

Comment: @KQI i add it wrong? Now code snipped shows like
    `get appUser$(): Observable<AppUser>{
        return this.user$
        .pipe(filter(user=> !!user).switchMap(user => {
          if (user) return this.userService.get(user.uid);

          return EMPTY;
        }));`

error is than
"Property 'switchMap' does not exist on type 'MonoTypeOperatorFunction<unknown>'."

Comment: Can you create a demo on stackBlitz and reproduce the error. It makes it easier to debug and fix.

Comment: i never used this before. Hopefully i did all right
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lqifhq?file=tsconfig.json

i changed user1 to user$ and some type things. So do not mind. (i uploadet my best version)

The Problem you found in `auth.service.ts`

Comment: oh man... i found the mistake.
@KQI in auth-guard.service.ts in the canActivate methode i did not change the route parametertype to any
and i guess some other missleadings from compiler cames from wrong compiler configuration in tsconfig.js
i had to add in compilerOptions "strictNullChecks": false, and i added also "strictPropertyInitialization": false,